# Have we seen any images of Pink Diamond and White Diamond in Steven Universe?

Tags: steven-universe

In Steven Universe, the Gem race is ruled by [The Diamond Authority](http://steven-universe.wikia.com/wiki/The_Great_Diamond_Authority). 
In the latest (by the show's chronology) designs, the Diamond Authority has a symbol with three diamonds.

[image: The new Diamond Authority symbol]

However, in older (by the show's chronology) ship designs, such as the moon base, we see a symbol for the Authority which uses *four* diamonds.

[image: The old Diamond Authority symbol]

In the Pyramid Temple, there were murals depicting battles that took place during the Rebellion. At least one of these pictures is identifiable as Yellow Diamond, and one matches a mural found on the Moon Base -- it's likely White Diamond.

[image: The mural]

Before the start of the second season, the SU team released a music video and some artwork with Yellow Diamond (who had not been seen up until that point). Has any artwork been released or shown within the show -- there's a lot that I could have missed! -- depicting (and identifying) White and Pink Diamonds?

[image: White Diamond?]

Comment: In the symbol with the triangles, it appears Pink Diamond is represented by the small triangle formed by the overlapping Blue, Yellow, and White. So all four would be represented.

Comment: @MarkEdward The overlap triangle isn't pink...

Comment: Well, that's what being colorblind gets me... My eyes are telling me the overlap is the same color as the Pink Diamond in the second image, but yeah, I checked and it's definitely just a turquoise.

Comment: I'm happy to relinquish acceptance to Ifurini.  I did the best I could with what we knew at the time, but I'm happy Ifurini stepped in with the final say --- the new answer is gold. :-)

Comment: @Praxis We just have to wait for the next revelation for a rematch! :-)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

During *"Back to the Moon"* (S03E24<sup>*</sup>, the penultimate episode of the third season) we finally had a chance to see the mural depicting **Pink Diamond** in full:

<sup>*</sup> I'm not actually sure this is the correct number, as *"Bismuth"* was a double episode

[image: Pink Diamond mural, top]
[image: Pink Diamond mural, bottom]

> [Eyeball Ruby]: Look at this place -- frozen in time. An era-one base.  *Her* era-one base. It was a tragedy, what happened to her.
>
> [Leggy Ruby]: Who is that anyway?
>
> [Eyeball Ruby]: Were you made yesterday?! That is Pink Diamond.
>
> <sub>source: [Steven Universe Wikia](http://steven-universe.wikia.com/wiki/Back_to_the_Moon/Transcript)</sub>

The Moon Base appeared in a former episode too (*"It could have been great"*, S02E24) but then only the bottom part of the mural was shown.

It may be worth noting that Pink Diamond's very existence, though heavily implied, was not *officially* acknowledged until the end of previous episode *"Earthlings"*:

> [Jasper]: I've been fighting from the second I broke free of the Earth's Crust, because of what YOU did to my colony! Because of what YOU did to my planet! Because of what YOU did to my Diamond!
>
> [Steven]: I... Yellow Diamond?
>
> [Jasper]: Wha... My Diamond! Your Diamond! PINK DIAMOND!!!
>
> <sub>source: [Steven Universe Wikia](http://steven-universe.wikia.com/wiki/Earthlings/Transcript)</sub>

**White Diamond**, meanwhile, hasn't ever been mentioned, though there can be no doubt now that she is the one depicted in the other mural in the Moon Base (the screenshot at the end of the question).

The day after the airing of *"Back to the Moon"*, an image was posted on [the crew's Tumblr](http://stevencrewniverse.tumblr.com/post/148756421602/joethejohnston-these-are-the-initial-diamond) showing the initial design for the mural:

[image]

**SPOILERS** for the latest batch of episodes made available via the Cartoon Network app on November 10th, 2017:

> In the episode *"Gemcation"* (S05E06) a brief flashback scene drawn in the same style as the one in *"The answer"* shows an armed and fierce-looking Pink Diamond surrounded by the Crystal Gems (Bismuth, Pearl, Garnet and two yet-unknown gems):
>  [image]
>  <sub>source: [post from redditor CaptainJZH](https://www.reddit.com/r/stevenuniverse/comments/7c3cfq/haha_im_finally_getting_backstory_oh_not_today/)</sub>
>
>  It may be worth noting that Pink Diamond's expression changes radically as soon as Steven tells Garnet he is not interested in hearing that story (accidentally causing every fan to cry out in despair!), which could either be attributed to fourth wall breaking or the story being not so genuine.

**SPOILERS** for the *"Stranded"* half-hour special aired on January 5th, 2018.

> At long last, episode *"Jungle moon"* (S05E12) gives us a clear, real <sup>+</sup> image of **Pink Diamond**.
>
>  <sup>+</sup>Though it's seen in Stevonnie's dream, so it could be not 100% reliable (Yellow Diamond appearance is mixed with Connie's mother's).
>
>  She appears much *younger* (as many fan theories suggested) and *smaller* than Yellow Diamond, with which she is speaking.
>  [image] 
>  [image]

Comment: Is there an official expansion for the symbols in the mural design? Pink Diamond's gem is on her stomach, and she holds just one planet with one moon (Earth?) contrasted to the many planets and moons of the other Diamonds.

Comment: If this mural shows the number of planets conquered (as has been theorized), this would place White Diamond as the Diamond with the most worlds.
Excellent work, Ifurini.

Comment: Nice work, Ifurini!  I'm happy acceptance was shifted to you. :-D

Comment: The PD dream sequence can be seen on [Cartoon Network's Youtube channel](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tSVZ8fADcg0). I initially added this to the answer, but apparently the video embedding breaks the spoiler tag, so I removed it.

Answer (score 10):

In the episode **"Sworn to the Sword"**, we do see a statue of **White Diamond** (as well as ones of Yellow and Blue) at Ancient Sky Arena:

[image]
[image]

As for **Pink Diamond**, as far as I am aware we have not yet seen a bona fide image of Pink Diamond, and the dominant not-so-spoilery *theory* is that

> Rose Quartz is Pink Diamond,

as is suggested by the Pyramid Temple — here's a better screen grab of an image you attached:

[image]

Additionally, here is a background panel used in "Sworn to the Sword" (source [here](http://stevencrewniverse.tumblr.com/post/128670833957/part-1-of-a-selection-of-backgrounds-from-the)) showing the four diamonds and the corresponding four statues, with the Pink Diamond statue in ruins:

[image]

Comment: Good catch! Can you get confirmation on the statues? Also, the blue and white don't seem to match the murals.

Comment: @Axelrod : I can't find an official statement, but a wider shot of Ancient Sky Arena (which I've added to the answer) shows four diamonds and four statues, which is pretty suggestive.  There were only bits and pieces of Pink Diamond's statue left.  As for the disagreement between the murals and the statues, I have no idea as to the reason (and there's no official comment on it).

Comment: Nice. I have to wait another day before you can get the win (the bounty requires 18 more hours and I won't allow any less reward than full), so if you come across anything else ...

Comment: Thanks @Axelrod.  I'll let you know if I dig up anything else.  :-)

Comment: It should be noted that time has shown most of this answer to be wrong - the statues are not not representative of the Diamonds and the interpretation of the mural is...more complex, to say the least.

Comment: @DavidS : Thanks,  It is recognized that this is a speculative answer that was posted 3.5 years ago, before we knew a lot of things.